# Questions about Protocol

Tags: support

Can I ask questions about SIP and H.323 here? Questions about standard SIP and H.323, not specific to any vendor.
Please suggest me relevant community for such questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact question it's a bit hard to tell, especially since SIP and H.323 could be considered a higher level protocol by just looking at their place in the OSI model, but often seen as part of a network engineer's responsibility, for example when Cisco CallManager is used. So it's hard to give you a 'yes' or 'no' answer without knowing the details.

One other stack exchange which does answer VOIP related questions for sure is https://serverfault.com. They have tags for VOIP and SIP which indicate a couple of hundreds of questions asked.

Comment: Well, it's like I am reading a book on SIP and also on H.323 and there are many things that I am not able to understand. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: I think [sf] is a better place for those questions than this SE.